# Is this theory trying to capture the theory of the minimal model of ZFC correctly formalized?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

I'm trying to capture theory $T_0$ written by Noah's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422463/at-which-large-cardinal-the-theory-of-the-minimal-transitive-model-of-zfc-start/422465#422465) to a prior posting of mine.

First we add a constant symbol $\mathcal M$ to the language of set theory.

Now we add all axioms of $\sf ID$ and $\sf ZFC$ in the language of set theory (i.e. just using $\sf FOL(=,\in)$, in particular not using the symbol $\mathcal M$), add the axiom of existence of a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$, the open explansion of which is a sentence in the language of set theory.

Add the axiom of transitivity of $\mathcal M$

Add the following scheme:

**Minimality:** if $\psi$ is a sentence in the first order language of set theory, then:

$\sf \forall N \, ( (N \overset{mt}\models ZFC) \implies (N \models \psi))  \implies  \psi^\mathcal M$

Where $\sf \overset {mt} \models$ denotes "is a minimal transitive model of"; $\psi^\mathcal M$ stands for bounding all quantifiers of $\psi$ by "$\in \mathcal M$"

Call this theory $\sf ZFC + mTm$

where $\sf mTm$ stands for theory of the minimal transitive model of ZFC, which are the axioms of the above theory other than ZFC axioms.

This way all theorems provable in "ZFC + there exists a transitive model of ZFC" to be satisfied by the minimal transitive model of ZFC, would be true sentences of the world $\mathcal M$.

Let $\sf minZFC$ stand for a constant set of sentences, i.e. some constant theory, so it is a constant symbol of the meta-language, then axiomatize:

**Extraction:** if $\psi$ is a formula in the language of set theory, then: $$\sf minZFC \vdash \psi \iff [ ZFC+mTm] \vdash \psi^\mathcal M$$

Is theory $\sf minZFC$ [effectively generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Effective_axiomatization), i.e. its theorems are recursively enumerable?

I think that $T_0= \sf minZFC$, however I'm not sure if the above way of formalization is correct. I mean I don't see the axioms of $\sf minZFC$, so is this a correct way of defining an effective theory?

Comment: Paraphrasing my linked post, I would just define $T_0$ as "The set of sentences $\varphi$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ 'If there is a minimal transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then that model satisfies $\varphi$.'" This is clearly an effective theory, albeit not very pleasantly presented. I *think* this is what you're describing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, this is simpler but also similar to what is presented here. $T_0$ is a symbol of the metatheory standing for some constant set of sentences, but what are the axioms of $T_0$? Are all theorems of $T_0$ at the same time axioms?

Comment: Yes, I'm defining $T_0$ so that it has no distinguished set of axioms; it's just a set of sentences, which happens to be deductively closed. There isn't as far as I can tell a more pleasant axiomatization.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Nice! A recursively enumerable set of sentences that are deductively closed, but without a distinquished set of axioms. I like it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, what is the exact definition of "minimum transitive model of ZFC" in your comment, if you define it as a transitive model of ZFC that satisfies absence of transitive models of ZFC, then I'd remined you of your comment before, if you define it as an element of a transitive model that is seen by it as a minimal transitive model, etc.., then its better do matters in ZFC + exists a transitive model of ZFC, as done here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, let $\sf M \models ZFC+ \text{there is no transitive model of ZFC} + V \neq L $ Now this is consistent isn't it, if so then $V=L$ is not among the sentence of $T_0$, I think along the definition of $T_0$ in your comments, $T_0=\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I misunderstood! Rewriting ...

Comment: No version of $T_0$ can possibly coincide with $\mathsf{ZFC}$; at the very least anything like $T_0$ will contain $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive models."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah! Yes. That's correct. I still think that matters needs to be done in ZFC+there exists a transitive model of ZFC, as the base theory. Well at least matters are clearer under this milieu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $T_0$ I had in mind was just the set of all sentences $\varphi$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "$\varphi$ is true in every transitive model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ such that $M$ has no $M$-definable proper transitive submodels." The bit after the "such that" is a strong type of minimality - in particular, it's stronger than merely demanding that $M\models$ "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive models."

Here are some statements which are in $T_0$:

- Every axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (since $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "Every model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}$," rather boringly.)
- "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive models."

  - Note that we **don't** actually need to allow parameters from $M$ in the definability condition: if $M$ has a definable-with-parameters transitive set model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then it has a parameter-freely definable one (via reflection to $L^M$).
- $\mathsf{V=L}$. Reasoning in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, if $M$ were a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg V=L}$, then $L^M$ would be a proper transitive submodel of $M$ definable in $M$.

  - In fact, the definition of $T_0$ above is equivalent to "the set of all $\varphi$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "$\varphi$ is true in every transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L+}$ "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive (set) models.""
- $\mathsf{Con(\mathsf{ZFC^-+ZFC\mbox{ has a transitive model}})}$ (where $\mathsf{ZFC^-}$ is the [*correct*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430) version of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without powerset). This is because any transitive model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ satisfies all true arithmetic sentences, and $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "If there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then $\mathsf{ZFC^-}$ + "There is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" is consistent." (There's less to this than meets the eye; really, the point is $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "Every set is an element of a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC^-}$.")

Comment: Without going through the details, it looks cumbersome, though it might work, but this might not be equivalent to the theory I've presented, which I think copies best the originally stated theory of yours. I think if we take our base theory to be "ZFC + there exists a transitive model of ZFC", then $T_0$ can be defined as the set of all sentences $\psi$ provable in this base theory to be satisfied by any minimal transitive model of ZFC. Which is basically the approach here.

Comment: @Zuhair That's equivalent to what I've written.

Comment: It would be nice to see the general line of argument for the proof of that equivalence.

Comment: @Zuhair I suspect you're overthinking this; it's just "implication juggling." If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a minimal transitive model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$"  proves $\varphi^M$, then (by the deduction theorem) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "If there is a minimal transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then that model satisfies $\varphi$." The other direction is just modus ponens.